# http://example.com works but www.example.com does not

Tags: azure

All, the title says it all. I have a domain name registered with GoDaddy and have set up a web app in Azure. In Godaddy I have set up my CName and A files correctly, as best I can tell.

I must have done something right with them as when I type http://example.com into the address bar of a browser, index.html comes back. However, when I type in www.example.com I get Azure's 404 error/page that says Page Not Found.

I'm baffled. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Please detail the exact DNS entries that you have set up.  Have you also added the `www` hostname in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure

```
A Record
* > your ip
@ > your ip

CName
www > @
```

Check you server config (for example I use apache2 in ubuntu)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/home/www.example.com/"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]

<Directory "/home/www.example.com/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

the important part is `ServerAlias` and the rewrite rule

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem